# send sms from php using local phone-modem as sms-gateway

Tags: java, php, ruby, sms, sms-gateway

is there a way to send sms using local cellphone connected to pc,from php web applications ?

i understand that it can be done by external gatways but unforunatly my php project is offline based. so i was wondering if there is any way to do this wihtout need for internet connection.

i have googled a lot and found there is couple lib for java like [serial-comm](http://code.google.com/p/serial-comm/) and [smslib](http://code.google.com/p/smslib/) but is it possible using php ?

im using xampp on windows to host my web app on local network

```
Apache 2.4.3
MySQL 5.5.27
PHP 5.4.7
phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2
FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41
Tomcat 7.0.30 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector)
Strawberry Perl 5.16.1.1 Portable
```

my project is based on php5-Codeigniter-doctrine orm-mysql-mysqlite

if it cannt be done using php, **can i some how code a helper with other programming language** (ror,java web,etc..) that would facilitate communication between connected sms gateway and web app with minimal messing with my network setup?

also can some one please explain the criteria of phone that can be used as an sms-gateway ?

Note: my clients sms traffic will not exceed 50 sms per day/per local-network/per modem ,
at most.

one of best resourse i found online about this topic is here http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp

Comment: Just about any language will do, right?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan at this point.. i'm desperate! im starting to consider .bat file to run hyperterminal and send at commands !!

Comment: I think all you have to do is open a socket and do it. Keep in mind not all modems will allow you to send SMS messages. First link on Google: http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/

Answer (score 2):

you can send sms using php but you have to setup a sms gateway server. you can then post/get request to that url to send sms. now that sms gate way server should have a gsm modem or a mobile phone connected.

**So requirements are**
SMS Gateway with GMS Modem / Mobile Phone attached.
A url on the server upon whihc you can send request